# VB.NET add text to the front of text

Tags: vb.net, string

I am trying to add text to current text that is in a textbox using a checkbox. Once the checkbox is checked, it will "add" the text to the textbox before the text already in the textbox.

example:

if the textbox said "Jake", it would say "Hello Jake" once the checkbox was checked.

EDIT: sorry for the quick question. I'm in a hurry. But the only method I could think of was concatenating and appending text. As far as I know append() adds only to the end, and concatening isn't the logical approach. I don't have a coded example because I dont even know how to approach this issue. thanks.

It's getting a thumbs down because its so simple, but not. I'm using multiple checkboxes. So one needs to be in the very front, one in the center, etc. Each checkbox injects text into the textbox a certain way. I can do this with nested if statements, but then we got a mess.

Comment: how about `TextBox32.Text = "Hello " & TextBox32.Text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this code :

```
if chbHello.Checked then
   txtName.Text = chbHello.Text + " " + txtName.Text
```

Note : if the checkbox is the trigger put this code in the checkbox.
          All it does is see if the checkbox was checked or not.
          When its checked just concatenate the text of the textbox and the checkbox with the
          checkbox first.